# What is the correct way to stop form input boxes auto-completing?

Tags: html, forms, autocomplete, input

I have a form which includes a JQUERY datepicker attatched to an `<input>` on the form. My problem at the moment is that since the input is a text-box, most major browsers attempt to auto-complete entries for the user, which looks very silly over the datepicker:

[image: (The auto-complete box appearing over the date-picker.)]

Browsing the internet, I discovered that way back in the days of IE-5, Microsoft had an attribute for input tags called "autocomplete", which could disable it. However, that was way back then, and that was IE. Checking on W3Schools revealed that HTML5 *also* includes an "autocomplete" attribute for input tags (yes, I was equally surprised that Microsoft was supporting HTML-5 way back in 1999...). However, our website is not on HTML5 yet, so I cannot rely on using the tag and assuming it will work. Taking these into consideration, how then does one disable auto-complete for a single input box in HTML4? Expected browsers are Chrome (latest), Firefox 3.6, Firefox 2.0 and - god help us - perhaps IE6 (although we have warned everyone that we aren't promising anything will actually work if they use IE6! ;) )

(By the way, for anybody worrying out there, I know that this is attempting to change a user's personal browser settings, which is a naughty thing to do normally. However, in this case I believe it's justified, especially considering 90% of my users won't know what auto-complete is or that it even can be turned off...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like :

```
<input autocomplete="off">
```

You can also dot it at the form level

```
<form id="stuff" autocomplete="off" method="post" >
```

It works.

Comment: It works... where? I had assumed the autocomplete attribute would work in at least some browsers, but what browsers - all major ones? Is it still the correct way to do it, considering that it's not part of HTML4? I'm sorry, but your answer seems to largely re-iterate parts of my question.

Comment: cf Zsolti, who answered quicker than me.

Comment: In the end I have just used this method. Thank you for confirming it, @Guillaume Lebourgeois and @Zsolti.