# How to make Chrome respect the names of my fields and not attempt to autocomplete

Tags: django, forms, google-chrome, autocomplete

I have two different forms on my home page: one for logins and one for registrations. As you can see from the code, the forms have inputs with different names:

```
<h3> Log In </h3>
<form action="/login/" method="POST" class="form-vertical" style="padding-top: 5px">
  <input id="id_login_username" type="text" name="login_username" maxlength="25" />
  <input type="password" name="login_password" id="id_login_password" /><br>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Login</button>
</form>

<h3> Sign Up <small>(It's free!)</small></h3>
<form action="/register/" method="POST" class="form-vertical" style="padding-top: 5px">
  <input id="id_register_username" type="text" name="register_username" maxlength="25" />
  <input type="text" name="register_email" id="id_register_email" />
  <input type="password" name="register_password" id="id_register_password" />
  <input type="password" name="register_password2" id="id_register_password2" /><br>
  <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Which renders to this in Chrome:

[image]

What can be causing this? And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears a similar question has been asked before:

[What is the correct way to stop form input boxes auto-completing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306920/what-is-the-correct-way-to-stop-form-input-boxes-auto-completing)

There is an **autocomplete** attribute you can use in form fields.

```
<input id="id_login_username" type="text" name="login_username" maxlength="25" autocomplete="off" />
```

Comment: Awesome, I'm going to give that a try (and figure out how to do it within Django forms). However, do you know **WHY** this is happening? The inputs have different names so why is Chrome filling it out?

Comment: That's a really good question and I'm sorry to say I have no idea.  Did you try to register once and also login at least once?  If so, that "might" be what's causing it as browsers come complete with the "autoremember" feature.

Answer (score 7):

> That's a really good question and I'm sorry to say I have no idea. Did
>   you try to register once and also login at least once? If so, that
>   "might" be what's causing it as browsers come complete with the
>   "autoremember" feature.

Assuming autofill is enabled (it is by default), the reason it autofills the rest is because chrome's autofill server works on regular expressions, not exact matches.

All the regular expressions used for the various fields can be found in [`autofill_regex_constants.cc.utf8`](http://code.google.com/codesearch#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/chrome/browser/autofill/autofill_regex_constants.cc.utf8).

From there you can see that the expression for email field is `"e.?mail"` and for username it is `"user.?name|user.?id|nickname|maiden name|title|prefix|suffix"`