# What makes a browser autofill email/password inputs?

Tags: javascript, ajax, autocomplete

I have a text input and a password input which Chrome often asks to remember the info for to autofill. The issue is that it doesn't autofill that information.

How do I get this to work?

It is a single page app, and all request are made via AJAX.

Hence, my inputs are as simple as:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="email" autocomplete="on" />
<input type="password" placeholder="password" autocomplete="on" />
```

I thought that the `autocomplete="on"` would solve it, but maybe it is because I don't use forms? Probably a bad practice of mine since all I do are Ajax requests, but how would I get this to work?

Comment: One quick question: Have you by chance ever clicked "never fill" when your browser asked you?

Comment: Nope, never clicked that.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome parses forms to autofill. So you have to put a `<form>` element around it, just don't add a submit input element and the form will not bother you.

See also this answer: [How to trigger Autofill in Google Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223168/how-to-trigger-autofill-in-google-chrome)

#### From that anwer:

> As pointed out in these [insightful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9492299/93394) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10361586/93394), all the regular expressions Chrome uses to identify/recognize common fields can be found in [`autofill_regex_constants.cc.utf8`](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/components/autofill/core/browser/autofill_regex_constants.cc). So to answer the original question, just make sure the names for your html fields get matched by these expressions. Some examples include:

- **first name:** `"first.*name|initials|fname|first$"`
- **last name:** `"last.*name|lname|surname|last$|secondname|family.*name"`
- **email:**  `"e.?mail"`
- **address (line 1):** `"address.*line|address1|addr1|street"`
- **zipcode:** `"zip|postal|post.*code|pcode|^1z$"`